# Listen to changes in Root collection cloud function in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Most of the examples i have seen explain how to listen to a document with the uid of a user.I am trying to listen to just the general parent collection

```
exports.sendNotifications = functions.firestore.document('Notifications').onCreate(async (snapshot) => {
    // Notification details.
    const payload = {
      notification: {
          title: 'Hello',
          body: 'Hello again',
        click_action: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com`,
      }
    };

    // Get the list of device tokens.
    const allTokens = await admin.firestore().collection('fcmTokens').get();
    const tokens = [];
    allTokens.forEach((tokenDoc) => {
      tokens.push(tokenDoc.id);
    });

    if (tokens.length > 0) {
      // Send notifications to all tokens.
      const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);

    }
  });
```

This cloud function brings `functions: failed to create function sendNotifications
HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors`. The error I am guessing is because the firestore collection is not being referenced properly. It is the root collection. How can I reference it better

Comment: It is not clear which collection you are speaking about. Could you add details of your data model and also give more info on when you want to trigger the Cloud Function (when a doc is created in the `Notifications` collection?

Comment: I need to listen to the `Notifications` collection when a document is added then send a fcm notification to the users I have tokens of.

Comment: Notifications(root collection)  - > documents       and   fcmTokens(root collection) - > documents. the data model is this simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several points that you should modify in your Cloud Function:

1/ You should trigger it when a Document is created, as follows. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=0#wildcards-parameters.

```
exports.sendNotifications = functions.firestore.document('Notifications/{notifId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

      const newValue = snap.data();

      // perform desired operations ...
      // You may not need the notifId value but you have to keep the wildcard in the document path
    });
```

2/ Also, note how `onCreate()` has a `data` and a `context` parameters. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=0#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created and  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?authuser=0#cloud-firestore for more details.

3/ Finally, you should return the promise returned by the `admin.messaging()` asynchronous task as well as returning a value in case `tokens.length = 0`. These two actions ensure you indicate to the platform that the work of the Cloud Function is finished. (I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/)

So, at the end your code would look as follows. *(Note that I've not tested it, so I cannot 100% guarantee that it will solve your "HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors" problem...)*

```
exports.sendNotifications = functions.firestore.document('Notifications/{notifId}')
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    // Notification details.
    const payload = {
      notification: {
          title: 'Hello',
          body: 'Hello again',
        click_action: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com`,
      }
    };

    // Get the list of device tokens.
    const allTokens = await admin.firestore().collection('fcmTokens').get();
    const tokens = [];
    allTokens.forEach((tokenDoc) => {
      tokens.push(tokenDoc.id);
    });

    if (tokens.length > 0) {
      // Send notifications to all tokens.
      return await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thankyou this is quite clear explanation with good reference, especially for someone who just learn firebase like me